# MariaDB tables getting stuck

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We've just migrated an app to a MariaDB and it runs fine for a while and then begins to slow down and eventually time out. The strange thing is, it seems to be only certain tables that are getting stuck.

I can do `select count(*) from foo` on all tables and it works fine except for 2 which just hang. Restarting mysql fixes it.

Does anyone have any idea what this might indicate? The tables in question are of the Aria type.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this was actually due to an unindexed query going really slow - which manifested itself in certain tables appearing to be stuck.